# При поиске в mysql по критериям меин выдает пустые скобки

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите,в чем может быть причина: 
есть sql запрос:

```
private static final String SQL_FIND_FILM_BY_DATE = "SELECT film_id, director_id, name, release_date, genre FROM film WHERE release_date=?";

 public List<Film> findFilmByDate(LocalDate date) {
    List<Film> films = new ArrayList<>();
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        connection = ConnectionPool.INSTANCE.getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_FIND_FILM_BY_DATE);
 preparedStatement.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(date));
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Film film = new Film();
            film.setFilmId(resultSet.getInt(1));
            film.setDirectorId(resultSet.getInt(2));
            film.setName(resultSet.getString(3));
            film.setGenre(resultSet.getString(5));
            film.setReleaseDate(date);
            films.add(film);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("SQL exception (request or table failed): " + e);
    } finally {
        close(preparedStatement);
    }
    return films;
}
```

в меин `FilmDaoImpl filmDao=new FilmDaoImpl();
        System.out.println(filmDao.findFilmByDate(LocalDate.of(2010,11,01)));`
выдает: [] (просто пустые скобки)

Comment: Ну во-первых, может оказаться, что фильмов на заданную дату действительно нет :) Во-вторых, может быть путаница, если дата зранится в поле вида datetime.

Comment: в таблице есть фильм с этой датой, дата в таблице в формате Date

Comment: Тогда попробуйте вывести куда-ьто в дебаг текст запроса после подстановки. Может быть - код лепит чисто секунд вместо выражения даты. Это похоже на Date.valueOf()